# Convert array of strings into array of integers

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, type-conversion

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.id, t.summary, null as worker, tt.worked from ticket t
INNER JOIN (SELECT ticket, sum(seconds_worked)/3600.0 as worked FROM ticket_time GROUP BY ticket) tt ON tt.ticket=t.id
UNION ALL 
SELECT ticket,null, tt.worker, sum(tt.seconds_worked)/3600.0 from ticket_time tt GROUP BY ticket,worker) as foo
WHERE id in ('9755, 9759') ORDER BY id
```

The ids string `'9755, 9759'` in the last line can and will change whenever the sql executed. 
I can convert the sting to an array like this:

```
string_to_array('9755, 9759', ',')
```

But is there a way to convert this array of strings into array of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the resulting array to an `int[]`

```
where id = ANY ( string_to_array('9755, 9759', ',')::int[] )
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm knew to psql and tried to cast it as ::int4 instead.

Comment: Or just use an `ARRAY` literal in the first place, e.g. `ANY (ARRAY[9755, 9759])`

Comment: That was the problem - the core of the system I'm working here can't pass anything but a string, so I have to create an array from it.